# setData in ListGrid in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt2, listgrid

Hi i am trying to use `SmartGWT`.

I have Arraylist

```
ArrayList<FileDocument> documentsArrayList = new ArrayList<FileDocument>();
```

// all the value are in the documentsArrayList

and a table

```
private ListGrid getDocumentTable() {
        if (documentTable == null) {
            documentTable = new ListGrid();
            documentTable.setSize("644px", "379px");
            documentTable.setCanResizeFields(true);

            documentTable.setFields(getStatus(),getIcon(),getName(),getSize(),getModifiedby(),getModifiedDate());
        }
        return documentTable;
    }
```

fields of the grid are like

```
public ListGridField getName() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = new ListGridField("name","Name");
        }
        return name;
    }
```

I want to put values to array list value to table.

documentTable.setData(some list grid record);

How to convert `ArrayList` in `ListGridRecord`
so that i can set the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a method which will accpet your `ArrayList` as an input and return an array of ListGridRecord which in turn can be set using `listGrid.setData(ListGridRecord[] records);`

Kick off Example:

```
 listGrid.setData(getListridRecords(employees)); // set records here 

 private void getListGridRecords(ArrayList employees) {
      ListGridRecords records[]=null;
      if(employees!=null){
       records = new ListGridRecord[employees.size()];
       for(int cntr=;cntr<employees.size();cntr++){
        ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();   
        Employee emp = employees.get(cntr);
        record.setAttribute("name",emp.getName()); //your ListGridField 's name
        record.setAttribute("status",emp.getStatus()); //your ListGridField 's name
        //.. more goes here
        records[cntr] = record;
      }

   }
   return records;
}
```

Another way could be [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/GridDataBindingListGridFieldsSampleSmartGWT.htm)

Comment: can you help me with this question                               [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10412060/780393)

Comment: :i am unable to add this records in table. I have added the printstack

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the class

A Array list can be converted into a recordList that can be added to the setData method of the ListGridField.
Below is the code snippet of the implemention.

```
`RecordList recordList = new RecordList();
 for(DocumentsArrayList documentsArray: documentsArrayList)
 {
  Record record = new Record();
  record.setAttribute("Name", getName());
  record.setAttribute("size", getSize());
  record.setAttribute("user", getuser());
  recordList.add(record);
 }          
 documentTable.setData(recordList);
 }
```

`
All the attribute name should match the values in the POJO so that the value object can be directly used.