# set the values in Listgrid (smartGWT)

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt2, listgrid

I am trying to use smart Gwt, Listgrid.

I am using both com.google.gwt.user.client.ui and smart gwt.
I have **value in a ListGridRecords[] records.**

***I am unable to set the values in table.***

this piece of code is in composite.

```
public TableDocument(Action action) {
        initWidget(getTablePanel());
    }

private HorizontalPanel getTablePanel() {
        if (tablePanel == null) {
            tablePanel = new HorizontalPanel();
            tablePanel.setSize("144px", "75px");

            addtable();
        }

public void addtable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(isDocumentPresent()==false){

            tablePanel.add(getNoDocumentLabel());
        }else{
            tablePanel.remove(noDocumentLabel);
            tablePanel.add(getDocumentTable()); <-- Error

        }
    }
private ListGrid getDocumentTable() {
        if (documentTable == null) {
            documentTable = new ListGrid();
            documentTable.setSize("644px", "379px");
            documentTable.setCanResizeFields(true);

            documentTable.setFields(getStatus(),getIcon(),getName(),getSize(),getModifiedby(),getModifiedDate(),getMajorVersiosn());
            addValuesToTable();
        }
        return documentTable;
    }

public ListGridField getStatus() {
        if (status == null) {
            status = new ListGridField("statusIcon","");
        }
        return status;
    }
public ListGridField getIcon() {
        if (icon == null) {
            icon = new ListGridField("documentIcon","");
        }
        return icon;
    }
.
.
.// similar code for getSize(),getModifiedby(),getModifiedDate(),getMajorVersiosn()

private void addValuesToTable() {
documentTable.setData(documentsArray);//documentarray is records
}


----------
error

    com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 12:15:47.778:WARN:ListGrid:isc_ListGrid_0:Unable to find clipHandle for drawn Canvas, elementId: isc_0
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
        at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid.create(ListGrid.java)
        at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.getOrCreateJsObj(BaseWidget.java:361)
        at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.getElement(BaseWidget.java:276)
        at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.getElement(BaseWidget.java:264)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:94)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel.add(HorizontalPanel.java:49)
        at com.client.SmartGuI.TableDocument.addtable(TableDocument.java:158)
        at com.client.GUI.TreeCmis$2.onSuccess(TreeCmis.java:157)
        at com.client.GUI.TreeCmis$2.onSuccess(TreeCmis.java:1)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
        at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
        at
```

Comment: I guess you have tried to mix SmartGWT with plain GWT.

Comment: @HardikMishra : I need a help .Plz Chk the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10449021/780393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not mixed GWT UI and SmartGWT. Try using only SmartGWT and see if the problem goes away.

You could starting by replacing HorizontalLayout (wich I suppose is GWT) by HLayout (which is SmartGWT).

Quote from : http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159

> Smart GWT has interoperability support that allows a Smart GWT widget
>   to be added to a GWT container and allows a GWT widget to be added to
>   a Smart GWT container, and it's appropriate to use this for:
>
> - incremental migration to Smart GWT, such as introducing singular, sophisticated Smart GWT
>     components like the Calendar or CubeGrid to an existing GWT application
> - using sophisticated third-party GWT widgets within Smart GWT, where Smart GWT doesn't have
>     corresponding built-in functionality
>
> However it does not make sense to freely intermix Smart GWT and GWT
>   (or other) components, that is, for example, you should not place GWT
>   widgets within a Smart GWT container that is in turn within a GWT
>   container. In general, don't intermix widgets unless the need for a
>   feature forces you to.
>
> The reason for this is that there are limits to the maximum degree
>   that two Ajax widget kits (including GWT) can interoperate - there are
>   no standards that allow interoperability in the areas of management of
>   tab order, zIndex management, pixel-perfect layout, section 508
>   accessibility and multi-level modality.
>
> Note that "bugs" reported when intermixing GWT and Smart GWT
>   inappropriately (that is, in contradiction to these guidelines) are
>   generally going to be marked WONTFIX, although we will revisit this in
>   the future if core GWT begins to support APIs that would allow better
>   interoperability.