# datePicker in GWT

Tags: gwt, datepicker, gwt2, uibinder

Hi have **Date in a string Format.**

*datevalue= [Tue Mar 06 06:00:00 CET 2012].*

in my code i have `textBox` where value is set.
when i click on `textbox` i see a `datepicker`.

what i want to do is , In a `datepicker` the `date` should be highlighted whatever the value is in `textbox`.

and also when i click `datePicker` the value in the text should be in a **same format**  as
 **[Tue Mar 06 06:00:00 CET 2012].**

my code is.

```
private TextBox getTimeLable(String datevalue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("date" + datevalue);
        final TextBox   timebx =new TextBox();
        timebx.setReadOnly(true);
        timebx.setText(datevalue);
        final PopupPanel popupPanel=new PopupPanel(true);
        DatePicker datePicker=new DatePicker();
        datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Date date=event.getValue();
                timebx.setText(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
                popupPanel.hide();
            }
        });
        popupPanel.setWidget(datePicker);
        timebx.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int x=timebx.getAbsoluteLeft();
                int y=timebx.getAbsoluteTop();
                popupPanel.setPopupPosition(x, y+20);
                popupPanel.show();
            }
        });

        return timebx;
    }
```

---

edited for error

```
errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Tue Mar 06 05:00:00 UTC 2012]

errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Wed May 09 12:00:00 UTC+2 2012]
```

Initially the textbox is with this value [Tue Mar 06 05:00:00 UTC 2012] .
but when i click on text box n select the date . date picker gives the second date in textbox Wed May 09 12:00:00 UTC+2 2012. The first one may be illegalArgument as it is set by me. but the second one is set by the date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat; 

DatePicker datePicker=new DatePicker();  // Have to make final to use in inner method


timebx.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String strDate = timebx.getText();
            DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {  
              Date selDate = (Date)format.parse(strDate); 
              datePicker.setValue(selDate, true);
            } catch(Exception pe){
             // setting current date
             datePicker.setValue(new Date(), true);
            }

            int x=timebx.getAbsoluteLeft();
            int y=timebx.getAbsoluteTop();
            popupPanel.setPopupPosition(x, y+20);
            popupPanel.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: am i using the correct imports `import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` cuse i have to inherit this     ` [ERROR] [myProject] - Line 652: No source code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

Comment: ` DateTimeFormat format = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` The constructor DateTimeFormat(String) is not visible

Comment: My Bad, it should be `DateTimeFormat format =DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");'

Comment: :your code and my code exactly does the same thing.
What i need is not this thing.
I have date datevalue= [Tue Mar 06 06:00:00 CET 2012] in this format.The dateValue comes from server, in textbox.When i click the TextBox the date which is in the textBoxshould be in date picker. and when i click the date picker the date in textbox should also come in same format.

Comment: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss vv yyyy   with format i can solve my problem.Thanks a ton

Comment: While setting the date from textBox to DatePicker.It never goes to try block . It all always set the current date.and also HH:mm:ss is always 12:00:00

Comment: Parsing is causing error. Put Sys.out in text box value and check error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10974/discussion-between-gamebuilder-and-hardik-mishra)